# cross-compiling from linux x32/x64 to netbsd mips/el

Tags: c, gcc, mips, cross-compiling, netbsd

I have some embedded systems which run on netbsd with mips processors.

I want to play around a little bit with them and as I understand it I need a cross-compiler. I have never done such a thing and all information I find is rather assuming in knowledge I don`t have.

so What would it take for me to set-up a compiler which compiles to a program which is executable on a mips netbsd system?

language is straight up c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to have the NetBSD source tree checked out and using the `build.sh` script to just build the cross-compiler.

> http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-build.html#chap-build-tools

Run `uname -m` on the target system to see the target machine type that you would use with `build.sh`.

For the different options to download the NetBSD source, have another look at the NetBSD Guide.

> http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-fetch.html

Note that you don't have to place the source code in /usr/src -- it is just a tradition on NetBSD, but you can freely pick any directory you want.

Comment: THank you! Could you look at this for me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976625/error-while-setting-up-netbsd-crosscompiler