# Error while setting up netbsd crosscompiler

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-compiling, bsd, netbsd

I am in the process of setting up a cross compiler for netbsd to sbmips with a mips64el processor.

so I got the source and used `./build.sh -a mips64el -m sbmips` and I got my toolchain with no errors.

I continued to configure the kernel with:

`cd /usr/src/sys/arch/sbmips/conf`

`/usr/src/tooldir.NetBSD-5.2.2-amd64/bin/nbconfig GENERIC`

this works, after this I go:

`cd ../compile/GENERIC`

`/usr/src/tooldir.NetBSD-5.2.2-amd64/bin/nbmake-sbmips`

which fails with error code 1, Here is a link with 2 screens. I cannot copy and paste since it all runs in a VM...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cUeA.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56M0a.png

Additional information:
My host is NetBSD 5.2.2 and I want to compile to NetBSD 5.0 my source is 5.0 also! I have allready tried to install NetBSD 5.0 and compile to 5.0 but it gives the same error. I am willing to install any version as long as I can can compile to 5.0. this install wont serve any other purpose anyway.

I am running it in a virtualbox VM

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that the architecture you're wanting to build is not fully supported by netbsd-5 (aka NetBSD 5_STABLE.)  I would recommend trying to build either netbsd-6, or -current (aka HEAD)  After all, 5_STABLE is rather long in the tooth, having been branched in late 2008, and released in early 2009.

With NetBSD's build.sh mechanism, you can build the OS from any POSIX like operating system.  I routinely build netbsd-6 and HEAD on a NetBSD 5_STABLE system.

Comment: really thank you for your help! The thing is I have some hardware which runs on NetBSD 5.0. I wanted to build some fun programs to mess around a little bit. But let say I try 6.0 or some other version. Are the executables I compile with that netbsd version compatible with netbsd 5.0? or not? I will try some different builds

Comment: As far as I can tell mips64el is not yet supported in the netbsd-5 branch (but mipsel is of course).  Executables compiled with toolchains and libraries of newer releases are not backwards compatible with older kernels.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of additional information please.  Which version of NetBSD are you trying to build?  It looks like you're trying to build on a NetBSD 5.2.2 host, but which version are you trying to build?

A side note, you can start ssh, and then log into the VM using slogin, and do remote displays back to your workstation.

Comment: I have added it into the my original question!